# Using gamepad without dynamic

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, gui-construction

I am a novice using Mathematica. I program regularly using c like languages though. Now i work on a simulation of a vehicle. I have a loop that calculates the next state of the physical model every dt seconds, and redraws the simulation using:

```
Dynamic[DrawScene[Refresh[AdvanceState[1], UpdateInterval -> dt,TrackedSymbols -> {}]], UpdateInterval -> dt, TrackedSymbols -> {}]
```

I am totally lost as to how `TrackedSymbols` work, or rather why it doesn't seem to work. I have tried virtually every combination of `Refresh/Dynamic/UpdateInterval/TrackedSymbols` there is, and the results defy all apparent logic. It is confusing.

Inside AdvanceState i have the following line:

```
throttle = ControllerState["Y2"]*1.5675 + 1.5675;
```

Now, if I change this line to

```
throttle = 1.5675;
```

the `Dynamic` above works as expected, it runs every `dt` swconds, however if I wan't to use the value from the controller, the function runs as fast as Mathematica can, seemingly because the value from the controller is tracked and therefore the function is reevaluated as soon as the controller value changes, which it does all the time due to noise.

How can I read the controller value only every `dt` second?

**EDIT 2!**
I use Mathematica 9, in case this really is a bug and it has been fixed in later versions

**EDIT!**
This is an example to replicate the problem i have. This should update every 2 seconds, but it doesn't:

```
throttle = 0;
dt = 2;
AdvanceState := throttle = ControllerState["Y2"]*1.5675 + 1.5675;
DrawScene[mState_] := Module[{},
demoArrow = Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, throttle}}];
Show[
     Graphics3D[demoArrow],
     PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {-3, 3}},
     ImageSize -> {500, 500}
     ]
]

Dynamic[DrawScene[
     Refresh[AdvanceState[1], UpdateInterval -> dt, TrackedSymbols -> {}]
      ], UpdateInterval -> dt, TrackedSymbols -> {}
]
```

Comment: Could you provide a minimal working example?

Comment: @Aisamu I added an example now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
RemoveScheduledTask @ ScheduledTasks[];

RunScheduledTask[c = Round[ControllerState["Y Axis"], .1], .1]

Dynamic[{RandomReal[], c}] (*RandomReal tells us when c triggers updating*)

Plot[{Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2}, GridLines -> Dynamic[{{1}, {c}}]]
```

So the `Dynamic` is not triggered by controller itself but by the value of it. It will not be triggered if the value remains constant.

Not general but quite efficient solution.

---

So in your case it could be:

```
ClearAll["Global`"];
RemoveScheduledTask@ScheduledTasks[];
RunScheduledTask[throttle = ControllerState["Y2"]*1.5675 + 1.5675, 1];

Graphics3D[Dynamic @ Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, throttle}}], 
           PlotRange -> 3, ImageSize -> {500, 500}]
```

Comment: Very nice workaround! Do you have any idea why the `Refresh` is not working with `ControllerState`?

Comment: @Aisamu I don't know. It seems that signal from controller has priority... It is even more annoying when your joystick is sensitive and does not rest at {0,0}, then you have signal flood all the time -.-

Comment: @Kuba I would argue though that the constant flood of signal is what makes it almost tolerable. It would be worse if one saw intermittent hangs due to control stick being centered.

Comment: @Kuba thank you VERY much for your workaround. I lost an entire day of work yesterday thanks to this. I will try it out in an hour or so, and return to mark your answer!

Comment: @mickey so don't thank me now :) good luck! :)

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to fix it, but the issue seems to be with wrapping `Dynamic` around any kind of `CurrentValue` information:

```
u = 0;
Dynamic[Refresh[u++, TrackedSymbols :> {}, UpdateInterval -> 1]]
(* Correctly updates: 1....2....3.. *)

Dynamic[Refresh[ControllerState[4, "X1"], TrackedSymbols :> {}, UpdateInterval -> 1]]
Dynamic[ControllerState[4, "X1"]]
(* Both update as fast as possible *)
```

Going directly to CurrentValue shows the same behavior

```
Dynamic[Refresh[AbsoluteCurrentValue[{"ControllerData", 4}],  TrackedSymbols :> {}, UpdateInterval -> 1]]
Dynamic[Refresh[CurrentValue["SelectionData"], TrackedSymbols :> {},  UpdateInterval -> 5]]
(* Also update instantaneously *)
```

Comment: Yes, this is what i observe to. Is it a bug?

Comment: I am not proficient enough to be sure...